# Is Main() required in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm totally new to .NET and I'm trying to get to know C# by running the codes I encounter in the books I follow..

I'm building a simple WPF app with a button, which should print out the hypoteneuse. 
My question is; In the bellow code example from the book, there is these two namespaces (Syncfusion and NamespaceDemo). Do I have to include them both? What is a better way to use these code? Secondly, When creating a new WPF file and a button for the application, it automatically generates this piece of code:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I know that the MainWindow() is for the design that will include the button. How does it differs from the Main() function in a simple C# console application?
I would appreciate a clear explaination about my confusion with how this different things has to be structured properly. Do I need a Main()?

This is the code from book:

```
using static System.Math; 
namespace Syncfusion  
{ 
public class Calc 
{ 
public static double Pythagorean(double a, double b) 
{ double cSquared = Pow(a, 2) + Pow(b, 2); 
return Sqrt(cSquared); } 
} 
}


using Syncfusion; 
using System; 
using Crypto = System.Security.Cryptography; 

namespace NamespaceDemo 
{ 
class Program 
{ 
static void Main() 
{ 
double hypotenuse = Calc.Pythagorean(2, 3); 
Console.WriteLine("Hypotenuse: " + hypotenuse); 
Crypto.AesManaged aes = new Crypto.AesManaged(); 
Console.ReadKey();
 } 
} 
}
```

This is my implementation, which unfortunately doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using static System.Math;


namespace Syncfusion
{
    public class Calc
    {
        public static double Pythagorean(double a, double b)
        {
            double cSquared = Pow(a, 2) + Pow(b, 3);
            return Sqrt(cSquared);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double hypotenuse = Calc.Pythagorean(2, 4);
            MessageBox.Show("Hypotenuse: " + hypotenuse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand a line of code, you ideally should not be using it. AES is not needed for your form or math function

Comment: Great hints. Thanks.

Comment: "My question is; In the bellow code example from the book, there is these two namespaces (Syncfusion and NamespaceDemo). Do I have to include them both?" The Syncfusion is only necessary if you're using one of the their features or components. The other namespace is probably for your book sample code.

Answer (score 0):

All C# programs require a `static` `Main` methods as an entry point. `MainWindow` is a class, not an entry point.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to place the button_Clicked() in the Main()?

Comment: @user9419320 not exactly. it doesn't look like you need wpf at all since you are using `Console`

Comment: I'm not using console. I'm trying wpf. but the code from the book is for the console. I'm trying to adopt it to the wpf.